# copy a file with numbers to another file with those numbers rounded

Tags: python

I am learning python and trying to copy a file with numbers to another file but with those numbers rounded (integer).

The source file is `fichiernombre.rtf` and has 3 numbers:

```
14.896
7894.6
132.278
```

The recipient file is `fichiernombre1.rtf`

For this I use the following script.

```
def valArrondie(ch):
    f = float(ch)
    e = int(f + .5)
    return str(e)

fisource = input("Nom du fichier à traiter : ")
fidest = input("Nom du fichier destinataire : ")
fs = open(fisource, 'r')
fd = open(fidest, 'w')

while 1:
    ligne = fs.readline()
    if ligne == "" or ligne == "\n":
       break
    ligne = valArrondie(ligne)
    fd.write(ligne + "\n")

fd.close()
fs.close()
```

I tried other ways but this one is supposed to be the right one in the book. However, I got this :

```
Drive/formation/python/exercice_95_arrondis.py", line 17, in <module> ligne = valArrondie(ligne)
File "/Users/xxxxx/Google                     
Drive/formation/python/exercice_95_arrondis.py", line 3, in valArrondie
f = float(ch)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:'{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1561\\cocoasubrtf600\n'
```

I really don't get it. Do you have a solution?

Comment: a ``.rtf`` file contains markup information (open your file in a plain text editor, like notepad and you'll see what I mean). what you want to do cannot be done that simple. use a ``txt`` file instead.

Comment: Hello, nice to see you joining StackOverflow. Please keep in mind that sometimes googling an error that you face might help you find an answer a lot faster than SO community.

Comment: I'd start debugging your code by printing your `ch` value. I guess @MikeScotty has a point here in saying that the format of your file might get you in trouble, plain `txt` files are much better for this.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. works perfectly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python script reads a file line by line, each line into a string. It then passes each string to the `valArrondie(ch)` function which then tries to create a floating point number from that string (`float(ch)`).

This operation fails because the file does in fact contain lines that cannot be converted to a floating point number.

The reason for this is that you are using a file format for the input file that includes meta information into the file (as was pointed out by Mike Scotty in the comments). `.rtf` stands for Rich Text Format. It's "rich" because it can contain meta information such as formatting as opposed to a plain text file which only contains the raw text characters and nothing else.

Make sure you save your input file as a plain text file. You can verify this by viewing the file in a terminal with a command like `less`.

So when executing `less fichiernombre.rtf`, you should see something like this:

```
14.896
7894.6
132.278
```

Not like this:

```
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 14.896\
7894.6\
132.278}
```